# regex n occurences of a letter anywhere in the string

Tags: regex

I have these sample text strings

```
my Mission was successful
my task was not successful
```

and I want to match it with a regex that states find string that has total 6 occurrences of letter s anywhere in the string.

```
s{6}
```

doesn't work, because I think it wants all 6 occurrences to be consecutive.

Any clue?

in a pseudo code I think what I am looking for is like this

```
count(/s/)==6
```

but I am not sure if it is possible in a single regex statement.

Comment: What programming language is it?

Comment: Somehow the answer was deleted after my comment of `.` matching the `s`. However you could use: `(s[^s]*?){6}`

Comment: Perfect, gaw's answer also works but the difference is in the matched string capture group. gaw's answer will capture enclosed string while blhsing's answer will capture the whole string in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^[^s]*(?:s[^s]*){6}$` instead.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/a9UE5K/2

Comment: but the . would match `s` as well, which could be an issue sometimes or? You can use `(s[^s]*?){6}`

Comment: Indeed I didn't realize the OP wants to match strings with exactly 6 occurrences of `s` only. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: thanks blhsing , perfect