# Regex to match a string that contains n+ occurrences of a particular character (anywhere in string)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to construct a regex that will match a string, ***when there are `n` or more occurrences of a particular character*** (anywhere in string).

E.g. the character is `/`, and n=2

Would give:

```
test -> false
/test -> false
/test/test -> true
/test/test/test -> true
```

How best to do this?

Comment: There are a lot of suchlike questions here, did you try any of the solutions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are many regex questions, but I haven't found this particular question.  If you have please could you share the link.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52420739/3832970, just one of tens I have just come across.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that and close if duplicate.

Comment: The technique is simple: match the char, then use a group that matches any chars other than the char and then the char, and quantify the group as you see fit.

Comment: Whether it will work or not depends also on where and how you use the regex. Please share your current code. [Do not rely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636124/regular-expression-works-on-regex101-com-but-not-on-prod) on regex101.com testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backreference:

```
(/).*\1.*\1
```

Comment: Interesting thanks.  Testing that in regex101 now, but haven't got it to work yet.  (I'm assuming the forward slash needs escaping).

Comment: no foward slashes are not metachars

Comment: @UpTheCreek This is the kind of feedback you will get if you do not provide 1) your programming language, 2) the code + regex pattern you are currently trying to use. Chris has a rich R background, and in R, regexps are defined with string literals, not regex literals, so backslashes need no escaping there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use capturing groups:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception
{
    final String input = "/test/test/test";

    final String toCount = "/";
    final int n = 2;

    System.out.println("Looking for ".concat(n + "x: \"".concat(toCount).concat("\"")));
    System.out.println("RESULT for \"".concat(input).concat("\": ") + filterChars(input, toCount, n));
}

public static boolean filterChars(final String s, final String toCount, final int n)
{
    // Oh boy, this is the best... string concatenation to create regex patterns... what could go wrong?
    // Please... think of the children
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + toCount + ")");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    int count = 0;
    while (m.find())
    {
        count++;
    }

    return (n <= count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capturing lookahead:

```
/^(?=(\/)(?:.*\1){1,}).*/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Gs2Uv/1/)